# Can I run single tensorflow graph against multiple data in parallel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, simd, parfor

Suppose I have complex matrix manipulation routine and I have implemented it as `Tensorflow` graph. Now suppose I want to run this graph against bunch of data, located outside `Tensorflow`. Suppose I can't represent this data as N-d tensors in `Tensorflow` and obliged to feed matrices by one.

Can I gain of GPU in this situation?

Can I do calculations in parallel? Some sort of par-for or `SIMD`? So that `Tensorflow` made a queue and allocate GPU resources as needed?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues

Comment: @Aaron is this about it? :)